# Need advice / guidance on makin registration form

Tags: php, forms, validation, mysqli

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color:red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$username = $password = $email = "";
$usernameerr = $passworderr = $emailerr = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {

if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
    $usernameerr = "Please fill username";
} else {
    $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
    if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/",$username)) {
      $usernameerr = "Only letters allowed";
    }
}

if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailerr = "Please fill e-mail";
} else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    if (!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailerr = "not a valid e-mail";
    }
}

if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
    $passworderr = "Cannot be blank";
} else {
    $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
    if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/",$password)) {
      $pasworderr = "Must be Letters";
        }
    }
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','my_db');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Fail to connect :".mysqli_connect_error();
}

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["username"]);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["password"]);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["email"]);

$sql = "INSERT INTO register(Username, Password, Email)
VALUES ('$username','$password','$email')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    die ('Error: '.mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "Registration successful";

mysqli_close($con);

?>

<h2>Register</h2>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

Username :<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username;?>">
          <span class="error">*<?php echo $usernameerr;?></span>
          <br><br>
Password :<input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo $password;?>">
          <span class="error">*<?php echo $passworderr;?></span>
          <br><br>
E-mail :<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailerr;?></span>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Hi, I am a newbie, and I need advice on making registration form. So here is the code for my registration form, the validation code works and it submit data to mysql database too. But, the problem is, it will submit data to database every time it loads (even if it is blank). What line of codes should I add to prevent the form submitting data when it is not filled completely / filled with the right format.
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check if there's any data in the fields.

Just add this line before your sql executes, after `$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["email"]);` :

```
if ($username != "" && $password != "" && $email != "")
{
    //your sql and rest of the script goes here
}
else
{
    //don't save the data if it's not completed well
    //do whatever you want in that case no valid data was completed
}
```

Notes: I answered only to your question but be careful, you have some implementation mistakes. You should just use a flag that by default is 1 and, if an error is found in any of your validation functions, the falg should be set to 0 and you should check the value of the flag before the sql instead of checking the content of the $_POST variables again.

Edit: BETTER SOLUTION FOR YOUR CODE
Add this block before the sql:

```
if ($usernameerr == "" && $passworderr == "" && $emailerr == "")
{
    //no errors, all fine we can add to the database
}
else
{
    //we have errors, do something but don't add the data
}
```

Comment: so after $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["email"]);

I added 

if ($usernameerr="" && $passworderr="" && $emailerr="") 
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO register(Username, Password, Email)
    VALUES ('$username','$password','$email')";

    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    echo "success";
} else 
{
    echo "Fail";
}

as you suggested, everything runs but now anything that I input, the outcome will always 'Fail' and it won't save to database.
Have tried some variations and still couldn't get it to validate and save to database.
Looking forward for your help.
Thx in advance.

Comment: Unless syntax errors in your code, the logic is ok. What you do is, if the validation did not generate any errors, the variables containing the errors will be empty so you can insert the data in the mysql database. If you are getting any error or you have any further questions, don't hesitate to ask. If it's working, please take the time to accept the answer. Good luck!

Comment: There are no syntax errors, yup I got the logic that when $usernameerr="" && $emailerr="" && passworderr="", it should save data to database, but now even though I fill everything correctly, it still fail and won't save.

Comment: Well, you did not write the code as I suggested you to do. You are not using double equal sign and also try to keep the spacing for a cleaner and easier to read code. Write the condition block exactly like this: if ($usernameerr == "" && $passworderr == "" && $emailerr == "")

Comment: oh yup, rookie mistake. Sorry, I am new at this.
Lesson learned, importance of == sign,
Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem, happens to all at first. You can read more [here](http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), there's also a === operator :D. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Please outsource your DB-Connection and your DB-Insert in some seperate files and speak to them per ajax-request..

your db-insert-query should be taken place after you validation and at the end of the

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {
```

block

Answer (score 0):

```
You did not close the $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST" block properly.
Also inside the if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") { block you can add another 
if condition as if(!empty($_POST["username"] && !empty($_POST["email"] && !empty($_POST["password"]) {....}
```